How to migrate script tag to a modern vite app
I created my resume on https://dev.sambarnades.com using a Bootstrap model.
Now, i would want to re-adapt that website and power it on Netlify with Sanity as headless CMS in order to easily & visually modify it through Netlify.
I created a react-vite app thanks to :
npm create vite@latest
Then, I copied & past the content, adapting it to .jsx format.
But it seems the former script tags aren't read by this new vite app format.

index.html (where is pointing the React app.jsx)
 <body class="index-page">
    <main id="root"></main>

    <!-- Vendor JS Files -->
    <script src="src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="src/assets/vendor/aos/aos.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/vendor/typed.js/typed.umd.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/vendor/waypoints/noframework.waypoints.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/vendor/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Main JS File -->
    <script src="src/assets/js/template.js"></script>

    <script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
  </body>
</html>


app.jsx (where I copied my content.)
function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <header id='header' className='header d-flex flex-column justify-content-center'>

        <i className='header-toggle d-xl-none bi bi-list'></i>

... all the code ...

 </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
  <a href="#" id="scroll-top" className="scroll-top d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><i className="bi bi-arrow-up-short"></i></a>
    </>
  )
}

export default App


I should see the exact same content as on https://dev.sambarnades.com but instead of it, I only see this picture & blank content. It seems that all the content which is driven by the <script> tags is not interpreted.

I will be very glad to have ideas & advice about this issue. Thanks!

Check the browser console. Copy any errors. Also look at the generated HTML, to see how the injected script tags look

I found the solution.
I encapsulate all the scripts url into constants in my app.jsx & refer them into an array.
function App() {

  const bootstrap = "src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js";
  const aos = "src/assets/vendor/aos/aos.js";
  const typed = "src/assets/vendor/typed.js/typed.umd.js";
  const purecounter = "src/assets/vendor/purecounter/purecounter_vanilla.js";
  const waypoints = "src/assets/vendor/waypoints/noframework.waypoints.js";
  const glightbox = "src/assets/vendor/glightbox/js/glightbox.min.js";
  const imagesloaded = "src/assets/vendor/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js";
  const isotope = "src/assets/vendor/isotope-layout/isotope.pkgd.min.js";
  const swiper = "src/assets/vendor/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js";
  const template = "src/assets/js/template.js";

  const externalDependencies = [bootstrap, aos, typed, purecounter, waypoints, glightbox, imagesloaded, isotope, swiper, template];



  return (

Then I mapped the array to inject the Javascript at the end of the code.
</footer>{/* Scroll Top */}
      <a href="#" id="scroll-top" className="scroll-top d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center"><i className="bi bi-arrow-up-short"></i></a>

    {
  useEffect(() => {
    externalDependencies.map(dependency => {
      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = dependency;
      document.body.appendChild(script);
      return () => {
        document.body.removeChild(script);
      };
    }, []);
  })}

    </>
  )
}

export default App


You a are missing a slash in the beginning of the src path;
//before
<script src="src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

//after
<script src="/src/assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

And your folder structure has to be something like:

this means the files must be local

project/
├── index.html
└── src/
    └── assets/
        └── vendor/
            └── js/
                └── bootstrap.bundle.min.js

And another way is to load inside the index.js or main.js file
import "./src/assets/vendor/waypoints/noframework.waypoints.js"

Also see this related topic

I tried, but it doesn't run.

@Sam i just updated with other ways to do it; Your answer breaks react rules by manipulation the DOM.  React automatically updates the DOM to match your render output, so your components won’t often need to manipulate it
